# xelatex not finding font on Mac

Tags: fonts, latex, arabic, xelatex, fontspec

I'm trying to use the polyglossia package along with xelatex to compile some Arabic text. It seems that xelatex is not recognizing the fonts that I have installed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Scheherazade} 

\begin{document}

\begin{Arabic}

انطلقت الثورة الليبية منذ أكثر من سنة متوازية مع ثورات الربيع العربي الأخرى التي 

\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this using xelatex, I get the following error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm Scheherazade/ICU
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation I for ICU.
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ICU
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2012)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf ICU
! I can't find file `ICU'.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ICU

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ICU

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ICU.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ICU' failed to make ICU.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Scheherazade" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.13 ...\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Scheherazade}
```

I'm on a Mac and I've tried to search for answers to this. I've made sure that the Scheherazade font is installed on my computer (it appears in FontBook). I've tried doing

```
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Scheherazade-R.ttf}
```

as well to no avail. Any suggestions? It seems like it's not recognizing the font even though it's installed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to update my MacTex to MacTex2014, which fixes this issue.